# Run remote php script from terminal

Tags: php

how would I go about running a script @ `http://www.domain.com/php/script.php/` from my terminal window. Also, I would need to pass a variable, `$var1 = "string"`. How would I do this?

Comment: Curl or wget perhaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use curl or wget to run those scripts, e.g.

`curl --silent http://www.domain.com/php/script.php > /dev/null`

As for the parameters, you could pass them as $_GET params, e.g.

`curl --silent http://www.domain.com/php/script.php?param1=foo&param2=bar > /dev/null`

Comment: What if a file resides outside of public_html or www folder ? Accessing via SSH ?